# Знаки вопроса вместо эмоджи при экспорте из бд mysql в файл .sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Я хотел бы экспортировать свою базу данных с эмодзи, но у меня проблема с экспортом. Когда я экспортирую свою таблицу в .sql, некоторые символы заменены на «?». точнее знаки флагов.
Например такие данные (США  ☺) стали таковыми после экспорта (США ?? ☺).
Использую mysql workbench.
в бд везде стоит utf8mb4.
После экспорта файл просматривал через блокнот, имелись знаки "??" тот же файл импортировал в другую бд, так же знаки "??".
Подскажите может кто знает как быть в такой ситуации)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, Вы пытаетесь их сохранить в БД в бинарном виде. Если Вы хотите выводить данные эмоджи в `html` странице, то храните их как расширенные html-коды - `https://snipp.ru/handbk/emoji`

Comment: я Эмоджи и использую телеграмм ботом, и проблем никаких не возникает.
проблема только при экспорте в экспорте бд.

Comment: Тогда нужен sql-dump из которого вы импортируете эмоджи

Comment: допустим я эти эмоджи вписал в бд сам. а что за sql-dump ?

Comment: Ну вы же не писали руками `INSERT INTO .. (...) VALUES(...);` - у вас явно есть пачка sql-запросов в вашу БД с помощью которых и были внесены эмоджи.  Обычно такой список запросов сохраняют в файл с кучей служебной информации (например: кодировка) и потом с помощью каких-нибудь утилит (phpmyAdmin, mysql commandline) исполняют на стороне БД. Этот файл и называют  sql-dump (правда в разрезе всей БД... )

Comment: понял. такого файла нет. это телеграмм бот записывал данные в бд, я ему сбрасывал пост он записывал информацию из него в бд.

Comment: Тогда разбирайтесь  с ботом - возможно ошибка там. Поиграйтесь с кодировкой таблицы. Либо бот не в той кодировке вставляет данные в БД, либо Вы их оттуда читайте не в той кодировке.